# Haml and Sinatra, where do error messages go?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I am experimenting with haml as an alternative to erb for a sinatra app. However if the haml teplate is not correct, for example if there is a problem with the indentation, all I get is an Internal Server Error message.

Do haml output more specific error messages elsewhere or is there some way to get more information about errors?

Comment: have you checked log/development.log?

Comment: @JoshuaCheek where would I find that? There's no such log in either the app folder or /var/log.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's Rails. Check wherever you're logging to, then (or set up logging if you need it -- googling "sinatra logging" looks promising).

Comment: @JoshuaCheek Thank you. That helped a lot. I got from the sinatra homepage that using set :show_exceptions, true caused haml's error messages to be displayed. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sinatra the value of the environment variable determine whether error messages will be output by default. Error messages are enabled by default by setting:

```
set :environment, :development
```

Alternatively to output error messages regardless of environment set it directly by:

```
set :show_exceptions, true
```

More information on Sinatra's configuration here: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

If you update Sinatra to 1.3.3 you will get proper error logs again in your terminal while running Sinatra. The logs were disabled by default briefly for the last two or three versions but back to default again.

Comment: That is very good to know. However for this project I have been running Sinatra via Passenger and could not find Sinatra's log, so it just seemed easiest (for development) to output errors directly in the browser.

Comment: you should have mentioned that you're not working in development mode. That's what I assumed. Of course in production mode you have to enable it by hand as ypu figured out yourself :)

Comment: Agree but honestly I had no idea about dev modes. I'm new at this and have just been using the defaults. Apart from the O'reily book on Sinatra documentation is far from newbee friendly.

Comment: The Readme is a treasure trove.